# a record and wildcard to setup subdomain by starting letter

Tags: dns-hosting

I have four servers working with a private web app:

- g****.example.com with all profiles starting with g ( g1001, g1002, g1002 ..)
- m*****.example.com  with all profiles starting with m (m1001 ...)
- s****.example.com ( s1001 ....)
- t****.example.com (t1001... )

i d like to setup dns record for my domain using a wildcar of some sorts:
there is  a way to setup a dns A record to something like

- g*.example.com  138.1.1.1
- m*.example.com  139.1.1.1
  ....

thanks

F.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, see [section 2.1.2 of RFC 4592](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4592#section-2.1.2):

"Labels such as 'the*' and '**' are not asterisk labels, so these labels do not start wildcard domain names."

What you are looking for is most probably a load balancer like e.g. [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/)

Comment: To be strictly pedantic, the OP could do what he is looking for by running his own DNS server (quite possibly as in his own software, not just his instance). But +1 for HAProxy, combined with a real wildcard on the domain, this would be the *much* easier solution.